# How Should I structure models of my contentful space for a website CMS

Tags: content-management-system, gatsby, contentful

I am having difficulties in structuring my contentful models. I want the whole content of the website should come from contentful CMS. Which approach should I use ?
Should I create a model for each page or should I create models of heading, images, body copy etc and then add all heading of my website in that and so on...

Please help!

It would be great if you can show some reference

Answer (score 1):

Content modelling is an art by itself. :) Rule of thumb is to build reuseable pieces. When you're building for the web I'd recommend to build page models which then hold data types for e.g. posts, authors or what you're dealing with.

[This guide](https://www.contentful.com/r/knowledgebase/topics-and-assemblies/) might help.